# Raphael get and Element by its ID

Tags: jquery, raphael

I'm new to Raphael.js and I'm unable to get a reference to an object by its id.

I use raphael (because I feel like it :-)) to create circle button at runtime.

I create one button by children of `<div>` :

```
<div class="elements">
<div>BUTTON HERE<img src="XXX" /></div>
<div>BUTTON HERE</div>
<div>BUTTON HERE</div>
</div>
```

Then I use one image already (XXX) on the scene to create a new image object that I put inside each of my instance container.

The problem is that later one, I ask my raphael object to respond to a custom event (**line 67 in my pastie**).

In my event handler (**line 62**), I would like to be able to retrieve a particular `image` (**with an ID set on line 21**).

Any idea on how I could get my `image` element by its ID or an other method ?

My function is here : http://pastie.org/3775836

Thanks in advance for your time and patience,

Jk_

Comment: can you use getElementByID instead of getById?

Comment: The problem is that the ID of the element as been set with RAPHAEL. It  does not have any proper ID in the DOM. http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.id

Comment: please set up a working example on [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net), to demonstrate your problem. anyhow you better pass the element itself (or the shape reference), or, if you wish to act on the callee - refer to `this` in the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an array (outside of your function).

```
var array = new Array( arrayLength );
```

Then rather than:

```
img.id = index;
```

use:

```
array[ index ] = img;
```

You can now access images by their index by looking them up in the array.